# Na oração "Não encontro muitas mulheres com quem eu goste de conversar", qual é classificação da oração subordinada "com quem eu goste de conversar"?"

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, modo-subjuntivo, orações-subordinadas

E por que o verbo gostar está no subjuntivo nessa oração? "Não encontro muitas mulheres com quem eu gosto de conversar" estaria correto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É uma **oração adjetiva restritiva** (ou, numa terminologia mais recente, oração relativa restritiva). Diz-se adjetiva porque exerce uma função típica de adjetivos: neste caso, modificar o nome *mulheres*; compara com *não conheço muitas mulheres interessantes*. E diz-se **adjetiva restritiva**, por oposição a **adjetiva explicativa** (ou relativa apositiva), porque restringe o significado do nome que modifica, sendo por isso essencial para sabermos do que estamos a falar: não te referes a todas as mulheres ou às mulheres em geral, mas apenas a um certo tipo de mulheres. Compara com o seguinte exemplo de oração **adjetiva explicativa**:

> A Júlia e a Joana, **com quem eu não gosto nada de falar**, tinham logo de cá estar também!

A oração a negrito é uma adjetiva explicativa: não é necessária para sabermos de quem estamos a falar — já sabíamos, Júlia e Joana; a oração simplesmente acrescenta alguma informação acerca da Júlia e Joana.

Estas orações distinguem-se por serem introduzidas por um constituinte (*com quem* no nosso exemplo) que inclui sempre um pronome relativo (*quem* no nosso exemplo). Daí o nome alternativo *oração relativa*. Esse constituinte é a mais das vezes simplesmente o pronome relativo (*quem, que, o qual, cujo*) que representa o nome modificado pela oração (*mulheres*) e desempenha um função sintática na oração adjetiva/relativa. No nosso caso é complemento oblíquo do verbo *gostar*: *gostar de falar **com mulheres***. Mas pode ter qualquer outra função:

> [Sujeito] Li o livro **que tem causado sensação** [o livro tem causado sensação]
>
> [Complemento direto] Li o livro **que me deste** [deste-me o livro]
>
> [Complemento indireto] Conheci a pessoa **a quem deste o livro** [deste o livro à pessoa]
>
> [Adjunto adverbial] A mesa **sobre a qual puseste o cofre** ruiu [puseste o cofre sobre a mesa]

### Adjetiva restritiva versus completiva nominal

Quando olhei para a tua frase, a minha primeira reação foi: é um oração substantiva completiva nominal. Só depois vi que não podia ser. Então é capaz de valer apena explicar aqui a diferença. Comparemos um exemplo de cada (oração subordinada negrito):

> [Completiva nominal] Eles têm fé **que tudo se vai resolver**
>
> [Adjetiva restritiva] Eles têm uma fé **que nada consegue abalar**

A semelhança entre as duas orações subordinadas é óbvia: ambas precisam o significado de *fé*. A diferença é que na completiva nominal, *que* não é pronome relativo; é conjunção, não tendo qualquer função sintática em *tudo se vai resolver*; na adjetiva restritiva, *que* é pronome relativo e é complemento direto de *abalar*: *nada consegue abalar a fé*.

[Este artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/as-oracoes-subordinadas-substantivas-e-adjectivas/29567) explica mais sistematicamente a diferença entre os dois tipos de orações.

### Subjuntivo versus indicativo

O subjuntivo *com quem goste* do teu exemplo soa-me perfeitamente bem. Já o indicativo *com quem gosto* não me soa nada bem, mas dada a complexidade do assunto não garanto que seja incorreto. Encontrei uma justificação para este uso do subjuntivo [neste artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-conjuntivo-numa-construcao-relativa-uma-pessoa-com-quem-possas-partilhar-o-tempo/35848). O artigo apresenta um exemplo com uma oração adjetiva restritiva, tal como no teu exemplo:

> Um bom amigo deve ser uma pessoa **com quem possas partilhar o tempo e passá-lo bem**

E explica que o modo subjuntivo (designado por *modo conjuntivo*, terminologia corrente em Portugal)

> ocorre em orações relativas (apenas as de tipo restritivo) que têm uma leitura não específica, ou seja, que referem entidades cuja existência não é dada como real ou cuja identificação não é processada.

Neste caso, a tal pessoa não é identificada; não sabemos sequer se existe. Também no teu caso, as tais mulheres não são identificadas. Tu indicas um característica que elas tem de possuir, mas não sabemos quem são as mulheres que a têm.  Compara com:

> Não encontro as mulheres **com quem gosto de falar**

Aqui entende-se que há um grupo de mulheres real e identificado; tu sabes quem são e que gostas de falar com elas; mas não as encontras. E neste caso apenas o indicativo *gosto* me soa bem, porque o grupo é real e identificado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Jacinto. Mas ainda não ficou muito claro pra mim porque o verbo dessa oração adjetiva restritiva está no subjuntivo. Existe algum motivo específico para isso? Obrigado novamente.

Comment: @HebertAG, tens toda a razão. Eu fui jantar e quis postar o que já tinha. Acrescentei agora uma nota sobre o subjuntivo versus indicativo.

Comment: Obrigado novamente @Jacito. Agora ficou claro.

Comment: @HebertAG, sempre às ordens.