# Isolando orações com vírgulas: qual seria o sentido da sentença sem elas?

Tags: vírgula

Durante uma revisão, me deparei com a seguinte frase:

> A planta nativa da Europa que é amplamente difundida e utilizada
> também na culinária brasileira possui inúmeros nomes populares.

Imediatamente (e quase que por instinto, eu diria), mudei para:

> A planta nativa da Europa, que é amplamente difundida e utilizada
> também na culinária brasileira, possui inúmeros nomes populares.

O que me parece é que, na primeira sentença, sem o uso das vírgulas, o que é "amplamente difundida" é a Europa, não a planta. Já na segunda sentença, quando leio, fica mais claro que as informações apresentadas estão se referindo à planta.

Gostaria de saber se meu raciocínio está correto e, principalmente, se a primeira sentença realmente dá espaço para uma dupla interpretação ou se é apenas impressão minha.

Comment: @ANeves, [*sentença* (Priberam 6)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/senten%C3%A7a)

Comment: A frase não me soa bem aos ouvidos. Se eu pudesse, reconstruiria da seguinte forma: "Embora nativa da Europa, é uma planta amplamente difundida e utilizada na culimária brasileitra, onde possui inúmeros nomes populares."

Comment: @Jacinto ugh :( apanhado pelas diferenças transatlânticas... obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

A função das vírgulas é outra. Expando o teu exemplo para ilustrar o uso das vírgulas. A tal oração, a negrito abaixo, é uma oração subordinada adjetiva. Não leva vírgulas se for **adjetiva restritiva**:

> Temos aqui duas plantas nativas da Europa: uma amplamente usada na culinária brasileira, a outra não.
>
> A planta nativa da Europa **que é amplamente difundida e utilizada também na culinária brasileira** possui inúmeros nomes populares.

Diz-se restritiva, porque restringe a interpretação de “a planta nativa da europa”, permitindo-nos identificar de qual das duas plantas nós estamos a falar.

Usamos vírgulas se a oração for **adjetiva explicativa**:

> Temos aqui duas plantas, uma nativa da Europa, a outra da Ásia.
>
> A planta nativa da Europa, **que é amplamente difundida e utilizada também na culinária brasileira,** possui inúmeros nomes populares.

Aqui não precisamos da oração adjetiva para identificar a planta — só temos uma planta nativa da Europa; a oração simplesmente fornece uma informação adicional acerca da planta. Por isso se chama *explicativa*.

Agora pensa na maneira como entoas os dois exemplos. No segundo, fazes uma ligeiríssima pausa antes e depois da oração adjetiva. As vírgulas simplesmente marcam essa pausa. No primeiro exemplo, não fazes essas pausas; lê-se “a planta … nomes populares” tudo de seguida; por isso não se usam vírgulas.

Encontras esta explicação na Gramática do Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (que podes ler [aqui na Gramática Básica Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/gram/cap16-03-subordinacao); precisas de scrolar para baixo um pouco para chegar às orações adjetivas). E tens mais informação sobre estas orações [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8006/na-ora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-encontro-muitas-mulheres-com-quem-eu-goste-de-conversar-qual-%C3%A9), e sobre a relação entre vírgulas e pausas na fala no contexto destas orações [nesta outra pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/ambiguidade-na-l%C3%ADngua-falada-entre-uma-restritiva-e-uma-explicativa/5282#5282)

### Questão da ambiguidade

Pode realmente haver ambiguidade. No teu exemplo não haveria, porque toda a gente sabe que a Europa não é um ingrediente culinário. Mas este outro exemplo é ambíguo:

> O primo do João **que é muito chato** vem trabalhar para o nosso departamento.

A oração adjetiva poderia referir-se só ao sintagma nominal “o João” (se tivéssemos dois Joões, um chato, o outro não) ou ao sintagma nominal mais longo “o primo do João” (se tivéssemos um João com dois primos).

Vejamos agora a versão com oração explicativa:

> O primo do João, **que é muito chato,** vem trabalhar para o nosso departamento.

Dum ponto de vista estritamente gramatical, as duas interpretações continuam a ser possíveis. Mas para mim a interpretação mais natural é aquela em que a oração adjetiva se refere ao sintagma nominal mais longo “o primo do João”. Isto porque nós esperamos que o locutor nos dê informação relevante. E se o primo é que vem trabalhar no nosso departamento, o que nos interessa é se o primo é chato ou não; se o João é chato ou não, não é muito importante.

De uma maneira geral, quando uma oração adjetiva explicativa vem após um sintagma nominal complexo que inclui um sintagma nominal mais curto (como “o primo do João”, “planta nativa da Europa”, “gato do meu vizinho”), normalmente a oração adjetiva vai ser acerca do sintagma nomina complexo. Porque a  oração explicativa é em princípio sobre algo de que estamos a falar (da planta e não da Europa, do gato e não do vizinho). Mas pode haver exceções. Nós podemos estar a falar das duas coisas:

> A mãe do Joãozinho, **que é tão difícil de aturar,** pediu-me para tomar conta dele.

Provavelmente quem é difícil de aturar é o Joãozinho. E  quem é que anda com grandes intimidades com a Ana neste outro exemplo?

> Ó Ana, a mulher do João, **que anda com grandes intimidades contigo,** é muito ciumenta.

Comment: Resposta muito boa, Jacinto. Acho que é interessante mencionar o sentido das duas frases de exemplo. Na primeira frase

Comment: Obrigada pelas considerações!